# How do you respond to questions or comments as answers?

Tags: discussion

I find myself struggling for the right wording to new users that post questions or comments as answers, so most of the time I will just flag them and let someone else provide the comment.

Here is an answer I ran into today: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31210/12189

Is there some saved piece of text that you guys just paste in when you see these types of posts? How do you comment on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you and welcome to GD.  The section you have posted in is for
>   answers to questions.  That said it would appear that you have a new question. 
>   Please go [here to ask a new question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and you can reference this
>   current question if it is relevant to yours.

That's what I typically use.

Rule of thumb usually if they are a new user they believe the site is treated as a form/board and not a Q&A board.  Just be nice, try to show it in your comment, then flag the answer and I or another mod will delete the answer or move it to a comment.

If its an answer of low quality I usually will monitor it, wait for a better answer to be edited but try to encourage a better answer to the new user and if a better answer hasn't been edited within a month we probably will delete the answer.  I tend to comment and delete down-voted answers if they hit around -7 but then they will grey out.

Same rule kinda-of applies to a new user that is referencing there site.  Encourage a little effort into the community and I believe the community would not be so harsh on votes IF they contribute.  Only providing link only answers is poor in quality but we also have to remember that some of us had to learn how SE operates so we must keep that in mind and teach.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to stumble across a post like this in the low quality review queue, there would be an option to leave a boilerplate comment:

[image: Add comment for author dialog]

There you'll see the "officially sanctioned" comment to leave on these sorts of posts. For ease of copy and pasting:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask
>   Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
>   button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

If you're interested in this sort of boilerplate functionality everywhere, check out this script: [**AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE**](https://stackapps.com/q/2116)

Comment: Ok, that's cool!